# Access value of object array Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, object

In my Angular 2 application, I have a calculation which receives data from different forms through a service.

I need to access to a value in an object array.

```
data: [{ "income": 12000 }, 
       { "income": { "name": "per Year", "value": 1/12 } }, 
       { "income": 120 }, 
       { "income": { "name": "per Month", "value": 1 } }] ]`
```

If I want to access to the income=12000 I have to use data[0].income. 
How can I access to the "value":1/12?

Comment: not strictly typed. `income` should of same type

Comment: By using normal JS object access techniques.

Answer (score 0):

`array.find( item => item.income == 1200)`
If you want to filter all items with income = 1200 than replace find() with filter()

Comment: Sorry miss understood the question ! Will change it accordingly,  but Aravind noted correctly that your data is not strictly type